# avaudioplayer playback progress

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer, volume

Would anybody have a link to a tutorial to add a playback progress bar to AVAudioPlayer?

I've searched extensively on this site and on google to no avail

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I figured it out and it wasnt too bad.

Just update it in a timer

```
playbackTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                     target:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(myMethod:) 
                                   userInfo:nil 
                                    repeats:YES];

}


-(void)myMethod:(NSTimer*)timer {

    float total=audioPlayer.duration;
    float f=audioPlayer.currentTime / total;

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", f];

    playbackProgress.progress=f;

    NSLog(str);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The `CADisplayLink` class, which automatically calls a method you define as soon as a screen redraw happens

`Timer` doesn't offer precise firing and can drift earlier or later than requested updates, and also has no idea about screen redraws and so could happily fire 10ms after a screen redraw just happened.

```
let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self,
                                selector: #selector(update))
displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: .common)


@objc func update() {
    let currentTime = avAudioPlayer.currentTime
    let totalTime = avAudioPlayer.duration
    let progress = currentTime / totalTime
}
```

Comment: Indeed timer is good, but this method is better for tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Add a periodic time observer and update the slider - 
in Swift it will be like this -

```
   func addPlayBackSlider()
   {
    playbackSlider = UISlider(frame:CGRect(x:10, y:300, width:300, height:20))
    playbackSlider?.minimumValue = 0
    let duration : CMTime = playerItem.asset.duration
    let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
    playbackSlider?.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
    playbackSlider?.isContinuous = true

    //If you want to manually set progressBar
    playbackSlider?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddAudioController.playbackSliderValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    //Here is the Observer
    player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
        if self.player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
            let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime());
            self.playbackSlider!.value = Float ( time );
        }
    }
   }

   //If you want to manually set progressBar
   func playbackSliderValueChanged(_ playbackSlider:UISlider)
   {
    let seconds : Int64 = Int64(playbackSlider.value)
    targetTime = CMTimeMake(seconds, 1)
    print(targetTime)

    player!.seek(to: targetTime)

    if player!.rate == 0
    {
        player?.play()
        playButton!.setTitle("Pause", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps :)

Comment: Adding a periodic time observer unfortunately only works for AVPlayer, not AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: **AVAudioPlayer** doesn't have `addPeriodicTimeObserver`.